# PySpark equivalent of a simple SQL join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

This is probably far to simple of a question.

But I'm not getting very far on my own.

I'm trying to use PySpark in Databricks to do the SQL equivalent of a lookup:

```sql
select 
    a.*
    , b.MASTER_ID as PLAYER_ID 
from vGame a
join PLAYER_XREF b 
on a.PLAYER_NAME = b.PLAYER
```

Note that the two attributes on both sides of the `on` are NOT named the same.

Can you show me the pyspark version of the same?
Seems to me the numerous tangential posts here for this are over the top complex compared to than this.

I found this and this is really close but the returned dataframe is all columns of ta & tb.

`inner_join = ta.join(tb, ta.name == tb.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can list out all the `ta` columns individually & alias the one `tb` column with:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

inner_join = ta.join(tb, ta.PLAYER_NAME == tb.PLAYER).select('<taCol1>', '<taCol2>', ... col('MASTER_ID').alias('PLAYER_ID'))

display(inner_join)
```

Answer (score 0):

logic:

1.) We first rename player_name in ta dataframe to player so that we can join

2.) Once the columnNames are same we can use a join using square brackets []

3.) also we dynamically select columns from data frame ta

code:

```
ta = ta.withColumn("player_name","player")
inner_join = ta.join(tb,["player"]).select(col(x) for x in ta.columns])
```